# Change the value of a TypeDef object already created in C

Tags: c, list, struct, typedef

Edit: Problem solved!

l The problem is not that my strcpy wasn't working, but instead, printing

l had to be done INSIDE this function. Outside of it my array was the same.

l (Probably because of strcpy works with references, but I dont really know)

l Moral - If you want to printf your string arrays after strcpy, do it in the

l same function of strcpy.  :)

l------------------------------------------------------------

Original post:

I have a simple TypeDef Struct project in C (code::blocks):

```
    typedef struct
    {
        char name[150];

        int studentNumber, present;

    } TypeStudent;



    typedef struct
    {
        TypeStudent students[MAX_STUDENTS];

        int qtdStudents;

    } TypeStudentsList;






    void getStudents (TypeStudent * refStudent)
    {

        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Insert name: ");

        gets(refStudent->name);

        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Insert student number: ");

        scanf ("%d", &refStudent->studentNumber);

        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Insert presence number: ");

        scanf("%d",&refStudent->present);

    }


    void NameOrder (TypeStudentList list)
    {

        BubbleOrder(list, MAX_STUDENTS);

        printf("\n\nStudents\n");
        for(i=0; i<lista.qtdStudents; i++) {
            printf("%s\n",lista.alunos[i].nome);
        }
    }



     void BubbleOrder(TypeStudentList, int n) {
        int i, trades;
        char aux[150];

        do {
            trades=0;
            for(i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
                if(strcmpi(list.students[i].name , lista.students[i+1].name) > 0){

                    strcpy(aux , list.students[i].name);
                    strcpy(list.students[i].name , list.students[i+1].name);
                    strcpy(list.students[i+1].name , aux);
                    trades=1;
                }
            }
        } while (trades!=0);
    }
```

As you can see, my project starts with an empty list of students, and with some "gets" it will setup some students, then I need to order then on a simple bubble order.

Problems:

1- My cmd is crashing when it reaches the order part. Did I setup something wrong?

2- Is this sintax right? (ignore the i's out of context)

```
            strcpy(aux , list.students[i].name);
            strcpy(list.students[i].name , list.students[i+1].name);
            strcpy(list.students[i+1].name , aux);
```

3- Whats the right way to  set the value of list.student[0].name AFTER the gets correctly?

-

Already tried:

Printing list.students[0].name after gets works correctly (so I suppose the problem is at my BubbleOrder syntax)

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please enter code directly into the question and not as an external link (such links can rot making the question useless for future readers).

Comment: Is this your real code? It should not even compile: `void BubbleOrder(TypeStudentList, int n)` second arg is missing. Please post a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Include `main`, ensure that it compiles and can reproduce your problem. Also which exact line triggers the crash - the debugger can tell you that immediately.

Comment: Not my real code, but the main part is there. I dont get why would the second arg be missing? It is called, Its (int) MAX_STUDENTS, the value is 150, its defined outside of this block (sorry for this). 
The code is quite long as its from my school study, and there is a lot of stuff commented in this same file, so its better to not post the entire code imho

Comment: It seems that strcpy is not doing its work, and thats the main problem here

Comment: Problem solved, edited the start of the post